# How can I get user data of currently logged user

Tags: node.js, http, nestjs

I'm tryig to get data from currently loged user, but i get 403-Forbidden error.

This is my service, where i try to get my data 'schedule' by user.id.

```
async getSchedule(user: User, response: any): Promise<any> {
const staff = await this.userRepository.findOneBy({ id: user.id });

if (!staff) {
  throw new HttpException('User not found!', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}

return response.status(200).json({
  status: 'succes',
  data: {
    schedule: staff.schedule,
  },
});
}
```

This is my controller.

@Get('/schedule')
async getSchedule(
@GetUser() user: User,
@Res() response: any,
) {
return await this.userService.getSchedule(user, response);
}

Comment: Are you sending an authenticated request? Seems like a guard is returning `false`

Comment: as @JayMcDoniel highlighted, 403 means the authorization check is already failed hence the it does not even enter the GET /schedule controller.